# Confusion Matrix of LSTM using Sklear getting error

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, confusion-matrix

I want to calculate the confusion Matrix of my LSTM model.
 Shape of y_test= (17799,1)
 y_Pred= (17799,1)
 I used thefollowing code:
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
getting following error:
 raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))

ValueError: continuous is not supported
both y_test and y_predict are normalized using minmaxscaler(0,1)
first few rows of both varaibles looks like:
y_test={0,0,0,0.0216212}
y_predict={0.000433061,0.000433061,0.000433061,0.000450924}

Please suggest how to calculated confusion matrix, tp,fp,tn,fn .

Comment: "ValueError: continuous is not supported": probably you have a regression problem (not classification), therefore confusion matrix cannot be calculated for the continuous (infinite) output range of the lstm

Comment: @Kaustubh is correct - you need to be sure it is classification, not regression. [Here is a similar question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33286/how-to-print-a-confusion-matrix-from-random-forests-in-python/33288#33288), where I proposed a way to get a confision matrix, in case you do indeed have a regression problem.

Comment: Its a regression problem. How can i calculate tp,tn,fp,fn in this case_

Comment: @Hazel - you basically need to make it a classification problem if you want to compute those metrics. Try the approach that I linked above. You need to make your target variable discrete, e.g. by predicting which bin the result comes into, instead of a concrete value.

Answer (score 1):

A confusion matrix can be drawn for a classification problem, where the Machine Learning Model (in your case LSTM) predicts the target variable into one of the N classes.

Can you confirm that your problem is a Classification problem and not a Regression one?

If in case you have a regression problem, then you might want to use a different evaluation metric.

Comment: its a regression problem. So how can i compute tp,fp tn ,fn in this case_